# Jmeter Mongo Db insert script is not adding iterations from csv data set

Tags: jmeter

**CSV set as below**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abbdo.png)

**Jmeter insert mongo DB script is as below**

```
import com.mongodb.*

import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings;
import com.mongodb.ServerAddress;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

import org.bson.Document;

import java.util.Arrays;

try {
MongoCollection<Document> collection = vars.getObject("collection");

Document document = new Document("_id", "${_id}")
               .append("has_mortgages",false)
               .append("data", new Document ("etag":"${_etag}")
                            .append("links", new Document ("charges","/company/${_id}/charges"))                            
                            );


collection.insertOne(document);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    SampleResult.setSuccessful(false);
    SampleResult.setResponseCode("500");
    SampleResult.setResponseMessage("Exception: " + e);
}
```

Thread group - no.of threads is 1 and loop count is 3

While running the script the first iteration is picking the value of _id as PT000001 and inserting the record. While
second iteration is picking up the _id correctly from the csv which is PT000002 but the
collection.insertOne(document); is still adding the _id PT000001

Can some one please tell me what is wrong with my script??

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) documentation:

> The JSR223 test elements have a feature (compilation) that can significantly increase performance. To benefit from this feature:
>
> - Use Script files instead of inlining them. This will make JMeter compile them if this feature is available on ScriptEngine and cache them.
> - Or Use Script Text and check Cache compiled script if available property.
>
> When using this feature, **ensure your script code does not use JMeter variables or JMeter function calls directly in script code as caching would only cache first replacement.** Instead use script parameters.

so you need to change `"${_id}"` to `vars.get('_id')` and `"${_etag}"` to `vars.get('_etag')` and your script will start working as expected.

`vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see the JavaDoc for all available functions and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) for more information on this and other [JMeter API](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/index.html) shorthands available for the [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223).

Answer (score 0):

Resolved after unchecking the below check from sampler

> `Cache compiled script if available`